# Difference between defining a value using variables and using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, string-literals

In the code below its written ,

```
char *str1 = "141";
char *str2 = "3.14"
```

but it could also be done as :

```
char str1[] = "141";
char str2[] = "3.14"
```

i know that the upper one is a pointer but here what advantage does it have over the normal variable declaartion?

```
// C program to demonstrate the
// functioning of the atoi() function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char* str1 = "141";
    char* str2 = "3.14";

    // explicit type casting
    int res1 = atoi(str1);
    // explicit type casting
    int res2 = atoi(str2);

    printf("atoi(%s) is %d \n", str1, res1);
    printf("atoi(%s) is %d \n", str2, res2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I depends what you want to use them for. The string literals being pointed to are immutable. Note that `atoi` is not type casting - it is a function which extracts an integer from a string.

Comment: Regarding to `// explicit type casting`: There is no type casting in `int res1 = atoi(str1);`, and ditto for the following two lines.

Answer (score 3):

`char *str1 = "141";` defines a pointer named `str1` and initializes it to the address of (the first character of) the string literal<sup>1</sup> `"141"`. The string literal may be in read-only memory. The C standard does not define what happens if a program attempts to modify the data in a string literal.

`char str1[] = "141";` defines an array named `str1` that is large enough to contain the string “141” (including a terminating null character) and initializes that array to contain a copy of the string literal. This memory may be modified by the program.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Technically, a *string literal* is a quoted string in source code. As the C standard specifies how a program is analyzed, processing a string literal results in creation of a static array containing the characters specified by the string literal, as well as a terminating null character. It is common to using “string literal” to mean that array, as well as the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In these declarations

```
char *str1 = "141";
char *str2 = "3.14"
```

there are declared pointers to string literals.

String literals have static storage duration  and any attempt to change a string literal as for example

```
str1[0] = '2';
```

results in undefined behavior.

So it is always better to declare pointers to string literals with qualifier `const`

```
const char *str1 = "141";
const char *str2 = "3.14"
```

In this declarations

```
char str1[] = "141";
char str2[] = "3.14"
```

there are declared arrays elements of which are initialized by elements of string literals. You may change elements of the arrays because they are not declared with the qualifier `const`. Also you can use the `sizeof` operator to get the lengths of stored strings like

```
size_t n1 = sizeof( str1 ) - 1;
```

Pay attention to that if you will write for example

```
const char *str1 = "141";
const char *str2 = "141";
```

the result of using equality operator like

```
if ( str1 == str2 )
```

depends on the used implementation: whether identical string literals are stored as one string literal or as different string literals. Usually compilers provide a compiler option that allows to select the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str1 = "141";
```

One major difference is that with a pointer such as above, you can change the pointer to point somewhere else.

```
str1 = "apple"; /* Now it points to the string literal "apple" */
```

However, any attempt to modify the string literal would invoke undefined behaviour as per the C standard.

On the other hand, if `str1` was declared as an array of characters:

```
char str1[] = "mango";
```

It would be illegal to do:

```
/* Error: assignment to expression with array type */
str = "banana";
```

because an array name is not a modifiable lvalue. Though, there's no good reason for this restriction that I know of. But the elements of the array can be modified.

Aside: There's no type casting in the below code:

```
// explicit type casting
    int res1 = atoi(str1);
    // explicit type casting
    int res2 = atoi(str2);
```

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string
> pointed to by nptr to int.